# Having issues comparing provided passwords and hashed passwords

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, bcrypt

I'm working on a Node.js application with user authentication, and I'm encountering an issue where bcrypt's `compare` function always returns `false` during user login, even when the correct password is provided.

**Environment:**

- Node.js version: v20.10.0
- bcrypt version: v5.1.1
- Database: MongoDB

**Problem:**
After successfully registering users and storing hashed passwords in MongoDB, attempting to log in with the correct credentials results in a failed password comparison.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
// User login route
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid credentials' });
        }

        const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!isPasswordValid) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid credentials' });
        }

        // ...rest of the login logic...
    } catch (error) {
        // Error handling
    }
});
```

**Attempts to Resolve:**

- Ensured the password is not modified before comparison.
- Checked that the hashed password stored in the database matches the bcrypt format.
- Created a new user account to test with a known password.

Despite these checks, the issue persists. Any suggestions on what might be going wrong or what else I should check would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that input password matches the decoded hash?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you share the code where you save the password (including where you hash it) as well as your schema and any pre/post hooks you have on the schema.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I figured it out. I was hashing the password in my registration POST route and in my User model presave hook. So, pretty much the password was getting double hashed.

Comment: @KevinRoberts glad you got it sorted. It is quite a common  mistake that the password gets double hashed in a hook.